# Elasticsearch 0 matches when it should

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

This activity is the one that matches with the query:

```
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "V47jV3oBb_MDv65iR4vj",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "ActivitatID": "30",
          "Nombre": "A la romana",
          "Tipo": "Proyecto ",
          "Descripcion": "Los alumnos y alumnas conocerán diversos aspectos relacionados con la Antigua Roma y utilizarlos para crear actividades lúdico-didácticas. Es decir, los chicos y chicas “gamificarán” el conocimiento que adquieran sobre los romanos elaborando un juego sobre el mundo romano, que será el producto final de la secuencia.",
          "Idioma": "Castellano",
          "Assignaturas": "Matemáticas, Educación Artística, Ciencias Sociales y Lengua Castellana",
          "Competencias": "Comunicación lingüística,  Aprender a aprender, Sociales y cívicas, Conciencia y expresiones culturales, Matemáticas y ciencias, iniciativa y espiritu emprendedor",
          "EdadMinima": "10",
          "EdadMaxima": "11",
          "Link": "https://descargas.intef.es/cedec/proyectoedia/reaprimaria/a_la_romana/_gua_didctica_.html",
          "Puntuacion": "2.823",
          "Votos": "10035",
          "Guardados": "994",
          "Tags": ""
        }
```

If I try the following GET query it works:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "Idioma": "castellano"   }},
        { "term": { "Assignaturas": "matemáticas" }},
                { "range": { "EdadMinima":{"gte":10}}},
                { "range": { "EdadMaxima":{"lte":11}}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but if I change "matemáticas" for "Matemáticas" or "Educación Artística" or anything else, 0 results are found.

Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Term queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) are not [analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html). In case you search for "Batman" in a field, it will only show docs which have "Batman". There will not be any analysis on your query.

Case will remain same. And even if you have spaces: "Pac Man", it will look for the exact same **term**.

Term query is not the best way to search if you want that kind of flexibility. If your fields `Idioma` and `Assignaturas` are text fields, you probably want to use match.

From the documentation:

> Avoid using the term query for text fields. By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields as part of analysis. This can make finding exact matches for text field values difficult.To search text field values, use the [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) instead.

If they are text fields:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "match": { "Idioma": "castellano"   }},
        { "match": { "Assignaturas": "matemáticas" }},
                { "range": { "EdadMinima":{"gte":10}}},
                { "range": { "EdadMaxima":{"lte":11}}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Field Assignaturas is of type text so tokens are generated using standard analyzer

```
GET index162/_analyze
{
  "text": ["Matemáticas, Educación Artística, Ciencias Sociales y Lengua Castellana"],
  "analyzer": "standard"
}

**Result**
"tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "matemáticas",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "educación",
      "start_offset" : 13,
      "end_offset" : 22,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "artística",
      "start_offset" : 23,
      "end_offset" : 32,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "ciencias",
      "start_offset" : 34,
      "end_offset" : 42,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "sociales",
      "start_offset" : 43,
      "end_offset" : 51,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "y",
      "start_offset" : 52,
      "end_offset" : 53,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 5
    },
    {
      "token" : "lengua",
      "start_offset" : 54,
      "end_offset" : 60,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 6
    },
    {
      "token" : "castellana",
      "start_offset" : 61,
      "end_offset" : 71,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 7
    }
  ]
```

Standard analyzer splits text and lowercases the tokens.

Term query

> Returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field.

So "term": { "Assignaturas": "Matemáticas" } is trying to match  search text Matemáticas with token matemáticas hence no document is returned.

You should use match query for this
match query  uses same analyzer as used in your field on search text so similar tokens are generated